# Will enabling proprietary drivers on 17.04 install affect secureboot and bitlocker partitions?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, drivers, bitlocker, secure-boot

*I originally posted this on AskUbuntu but it was suggested to me in the comments that this might be a better place.*

I have a Windows 10 Bitlocker partition that if I understand correctly requires SecureBoot to be enabled.

The BIOS in my Asus Z170-A motherboard does not give me the option to disable this, so I cannot test if it will boot without it.

I have attempted to install Ubuntu 17.04 alongside windows and the installer froze with nouveau sched_error messages presumably because of my graphics card, a 1080 Ti.

By adding nomodeset to the boot options I was able to get the disk to install. I did not select "install proprietary drivers" because the prompt warned that it would disable secure boot, which I feared would permanently prevent me from booting into Windows 10.

The install was successful, but presented me with a purple screen on launch, until I again added nomodeset to the boot options.

I was able to log in, and the system worked fine, but at low resolution with massive screen tearing.

I ended up deleting the partition, and want to try again from scratch.

If I enable the proprietary drivers, will it effect my ability to boot into a bitlocker encrypted drive?

Will it fix my graphical issues?

Comment: Bitlocker requires UEFI to be enabled but doesn't require secure boot to be enabled.

Comment: I use proprietary drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 without losing secure boot. I do this by self-signing the drivers. It is a bit of a hassle - the signing has to be repeated every time the kernel is updated, but I put up with it, rather than disabling secure boot. I used the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/gabrieljcs/68939c7eeadfabfdbc6b40100130270d) for VMware drivers (which are compiled on the fly for each kernel and are therefore unsigned) and adapted it for other proprietary drivers. Once scripts are created for each driver, it is a straightforward procedure.